# How to Run Flask Based Web Page on Ubuntu Server Which Already Serving PHP Website

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

I want to serve a flask based web page on my already running PHP website. My web directory looks like below.

index.php  (So can be seen in mysite.com )

inside contact folder index.php (can be seen in mysite.com/contact/ )

inside about folder index.php (can be seen in mysite.com/about/ )

inside "mypost" folder index.php (can be seen in mysite.com/mypost/ )

inside "flaskbasedapp" folder I wanna use python & flask based web app

So that I can serve in (mysite.com/flaskbasedapp)

Can anyone help me what should I do without affecting my php based webpages

Answer (score 1):

You need something to launch your flask app and keep it running. I use [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) for that. Once it's up, you can configure your web server to pass certain paths to that running flask app.

Here's an example of how to do this with nginx:

```
location /flaskbasedapp {
    try_files $uri @flask;
}

location @flask {
    uwsgi_pass unix:/path/to/uwsgi/socket-file.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your flask app parallelly and use its endpoint link on your current page or you can create an iframe having the link of your flask route which is serving the HTML page.

Let me know if this works otherwise we'll figure this out.